# How to make UserControl dependencies required at design/compile time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a UserControl that exposes some dependency properties, which must be populated for the control to work.

When I use the control in XAML, I can provide values for the dependency properties.  But if I fail to set all values, it won't be apparent until run-time (exception will be thrown).

Is there any way for a UserControl to mark certain dependencies as required?  If this were a plain C# class, I would make its dependencies as constructor parameters.  But I'm not sure what's the right way to something similar in the WPF/XAML world.

We're using .NET 3.5 and VisualStudio 2008.

Comment: Good question, but would that be good design? When i drag a control from the toolbox onto my window, i would expect it to work without the need to set some properties. I could of course image a control that renders an error/information message in its visual area until all necessary properties are set. Think of the Bing Maps control that shows an error until you set the CredentialsProvider property.

Comment: It's always best to provide default values for dependency properties

Comment: @Rachel, how to provide a default value for Map.CredentialsProvider? It contains an application specific id that only the application author can provide.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, our control needs to communicate with a web-service, and so it requires the web-service URL to be passed in.  If I forget to set the URL, the control cannot work at runtime.  Is there a better way to design this?

Comment: No. Since you might not be able to provide a sensible default value for the URL, a good way to inform the developer of that fact is to render a message like "Please specify server URL" or so as long as the property has not been set.

Comment: @Clemens In that case, I'd leave the default credentials as `null` and make sure there is error handling behind the control so it doesn't throw an exception at run-time. Developers will notice fairly quickly that something isn't correct if the UserControl doesn't work as expected or displays an error at run-time.

Comment: @Rachel, of course, but the question here was how to handle such a situation at design time.

Comment: @Clemens Want to provide an answer, and I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to let the control render an error message in its visual area, that during design time hints the developer at these properties and urges him to assign values to them.

An example of such a behaviour is the Bing Maps Control, which requires its CredentialsProvider property to be set by the application programmer. As long as the CredentialsProvider isn't set, the map shows a large label in its center with an appropriate message.

In contrast to the Bing Maps Control you may consider to show such a message at design time only and during runtime throw an exception instead.